Django drf-spectacular show permissions for each view
I'd like to show the necessary permissions for each API endpoint in my Swagger UI. I'm not finding any relevant documentation.
So something like:
@extend_schema(
    description="Get all responsible parties",
    responses={200: ResponsiblePartySerializer},
    permissions=[responsible_party.can_view_responsible_party]
)

Does this exist or how would you accomplish showing the permissions for each API route?
